# Spring OAuth2.0 - Dynamically register OAuth2.0 client

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am working on setting up an OAuth2.0 authorization server using Spring security. I want to know if there is a way to dynamically register an OAuth2.0 client after the OAuth2.0 authorization server is up and running?

Basically, I know that I can register a client while configuring the OAuth2.0 server by extending the `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter` and overriding the configure method to add the client details in memory. However, this way the client is pre-registered and I would like to know how to dynamically add the client details.

`@Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient(CLIENT_ID)
                    .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "implicit")
                    .redirectUris("http://junk/")
                    .scopes("cn")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(600);
            // @formatter:on
        }`

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to just use the `JdbcClientDetails` (there are even convenience methods similar to the in memory ones):

```
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
        ... etc.
```

(Code taken from here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/tests/annotation/jdbc/src/main/java/demo/Application.java#L102.) Then you have a database with data you can change at runtime as much as you want.